# Ignore "Bad: new and old password are too similar"

Tags: password

I receive this message when trying to change my password:

"Bad: new and old password are too similar"

The passwords' "similarity" is irrelevant for my needs, so I'd like to bypass this.

I tried `sudo passwd $my_username`

I thought this had worked because I got a message:

```
passwd: password updated successfully
```

However, the password change has no effect after leaving the terminal, and my old password is still the only one recognized.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: The result shows that your password has been updated sucessfully. Just logout and login back to confirm.

Comment: I've logged out and back in, and rebooted my machine. No effect - the old password remains.

Comment: What version of ubuntu you are using? Try changing the user password using GUI method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using 11.04. Unfortunately, the GUI method doesn't allow a 'similar' password. If what I've done above is seemingly correct, then I'll just need to choose a different type of password. I'm just surprised the sudo method isn't working for me.

Comment: @user999 maybe a stupid question on my part but did you actually use $my_username or did you change that to your username?

Comment: @Rinzwind yes, i used my own username :)

Comment: @user999 I can even change my password without it nagging about it being too short (used 1 letter to test ;)) or it being the same as used before or even being the same password as it already is.

Comment: @Rinzwind I see, and you're typing exactly as I've done above? thanks

Comment: @user999 Yes I did.

Comment: Okay, I tried once more with sudo command line, but this time chose a completely different, not similar, password. This still didn't work. I then attempted to change my password to a non-similar one with the GUI tool. This has worked. Haven't solved the original problem of wanting a similar password, but at least i've finally managed to change my password. Happy to move on now with the rest of the day... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 62):

For me I was able to avoid this message:

`Bad: new password is just a wrapped version of the old one` (and a few other similar messages)

by running `$sudo passwd <my_username>` instead of just `$ passwd`

Just obviously be aware of the security implications but at least it allows it now.

Comment: Damn, this doesn't work (anymore? Ubuntu 20)

Answer (score 23):

A workaround would be to change the old password to a random one, and change it again to a similar one. The password history is not preserved, so this should work fine.

If you need a real solution, please include the contents of your `/etc/pam.d/common-password` and `/etc/pam.d/chpasswd` (preferably using a pastebin).

Comment: If using the workaround, remember that there are other limitations to be aware of in more recent versions of Ubuntu. "New password is too simple" and "You must choose a longer password" are just two.

Comment: also, note that some systems are configured to not let you change the password more than once a day, in order to avoid exactly this (stupid corporate rules). So make sure you save that temporary password well

Answer (score 3):

`sudo chage -l username`

- Use this command to view your current password expiration policies.

`sudo chage username`

- Use this to get change the different password expiration policy fields; set `Minimum Password Age` to `0` and set `Maximum Password Age` to `99999` to keep your current password indefinitely and don't want it to expire.

More info: [Ubuntu Server Guide - Ubuntu User Management: Password Expiration](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/user-management.html)

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/user-management.html doesn't seem to list the relevant options - it mentions `/etc/pam.d/common-password` but without details of what precisely is meant by rule-sets like **`nullok_secure`** or what other rule-sets are available.

Mentioning a document like **`man pam_unix`** might be useful here?

Comment: Hi OJW! Your post doesn't seem to attempt to answer the question. Did you mean this as a comment to 13east's answer?