# How do I improve my password after being denied (password too similiar to previous password)

Tags: 20.04, password

I tried to change my password (on MY machine), was denied, password too similar to old password. Just want to add a few characters so I can improve it, but still REMEMBER it!

Comment: I am voting to close this question since the problem cannot be reproduced and is unlikely to be helpful for future visitors. For those looking for a question about how to change your password, we have [Change password on root user and user account](https://askubuntu.com/q/423942).

Comment: "Cannot be reproduced"? It happened to me, my new password contained the character string from the old password, Ubuntu wouldn't let me use the modified password.  How would you know my suggestion is "unlikely to be helpful"?

Comment: Here is another question about trying to change the password when it is too similar to the current password: [New and old password are too similar](https://askubuntu.com/q/44276).

Comment: I had not seen that one, thanks, a lot more info there!

Comment: That will teach me not to share solutions to problems, I lost 4 reputation points because I did not search thoroughly the first time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using sudo fixed my problem,  but that post has a lot more info. Thx for more info.

Answer (score -2):

Found it, simple, should have known.
Entered in terminal: "sudo passwd (my user name)", that worked.
Added 4 characters, now maybe I can remember new password!